# Export datatable to crystal report

Tags: vb.net, datatable, crystal-reports, xsd

I created a datatable (.xsd) that corresponds to the datatable I coded in the code-behind.

[image: Figure 1]

```
Protected Sub btnDproceed_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDproceed.Click


    '---> ASSUME THAT I CODES FOR THE FIRST FOUR COLUMNS OF DATATABLE IS MADE HERE
    '---> CREATE DYNAMIC COLUMNS OF SCORES
    cn.Open()
    '---> SQL COMMAND HERE THAT GET TOP 5 DATA FROM DATABASE USED TO GENERATE 5 ADDITIONAL COLUMNS IN dt
    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Do While rs.Read
        Dim gwno As String = rs.Item("GWNO").ToString
        If gwno.Length = 1 Then
            gwno = "0" & gwno
        End If
        Dim vHeader As String = "LES" & gwno & "_" & rs.Item("GWTYPE")
        If Not dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader) Then
            Dim f As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader, GetType(System.String))
            dt.Columns.Add(f)
            f.AllowDBNull = True
        End If
    Loop
    cn.Close()

    '---> DATA ROWS FOR SCORES
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If Not dt.Columns.Contains("RANK") Then
            dt.Columns.Add("RANK").SetOrdinal(0)
        End If
        Dim v As Integer
        v = v + 1
        row(0) = v.ToString
        For col As Integer = 4 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            '---> SQL COMMAND THAT GETS DATA (score) BASED ON THE 5 GENERATED COLUMNS ABOVE
            rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If rs.Read = True Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rs.Item("SCORE").ToString) Then
                    row(col) = rs.Item("SCORE").ToString
                Else
                    row(col) = rs.Item("REMTYPE").ToString
                End If
            End If
            cn.Close()
        Next
    Next

    '---> ADDITIONAL STATIC COLUMNS
    dt.Columns.Add("LE_SUM")
    dt.Columns.Add("LE_CNT")
    dt.Columns.Add("LE_AVE")
    dt.Columns.Add("UE_SUM")
    dt.Columns.Add("UE_CNT")
    dt.Columns.Add("UE_AVE")
    dt.Columns.Add("AVERAGE")
    dt.Columns.Add("CGRADE")
    dt.Columns.Add("+/-GPTS")
    dt.Columns.Add("CRANK")
    dt.Columns.Add("DEF")
    dt.Columns.Add("EXPTD")
    dt.Columns.Add("ABCNT")
    dt.Columns.Add("INC")

    Dim crpt As New ReportDocument()
    CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = False
    crpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"))
    crpt.SetDataSource(dt)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crpt
End Sub
```

As seen above, the `dt` and `Scores.xsd` has similar datacolumns which will be used in generating the crystal report (yes, it's working). But the problems are the Top 5 columns and it's corresponding data. In `Scores.xsd`, `DataColumn5` to `DataColumn9` and `DataColumn24` to `DataColumn28` can't generate data in Crystal Report since in `datatable dt`, there's no same name datacolumns. Now, how can I make there columns in Crystal Report since these columns are changing depending on the `Top 5`.

Comment: Crystal report does not allow modification at runtime. so, it is not possible to rename the column or add a new column during the execution. You have to make column name static.